# In a BST, find count of nodes smaller/greater than a given node in O(log N)?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Given a BST (Binary Search Tree), how to count number of nodes smaller/larger than a given node in O(log N). 
Assume you can modify the Node to add more variables into it, and while you are building the tree, it's ok to do operations as long as they are less than O(n^2).

Also it would help to provide a picture to visualize what subtrees should be considered.

Comment: 1)build balanced BST, with nodes having knowledge of how many children they have that is updated whenever a node is inserted. 2) find node, read from field

Comment: Keep in each node the number of leaves below it. When you add  a leaf while building the tree, as you unwind the stack you built to get here, add one to the size to every parent (that's an O(logn n) operation). Then the number smaller than node n is n.left.size, bigger n.right.size), i.e constant time.

Comment: @Paul, that's not all the nodes smaller than current node. That's only part of the answer. There are other nodes to consider too.

Comment: @apadana, Ah yes. Oops

Comment: I wish people giving negative points leaving a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic use of an *augmented search tree*. Basically, you augment the BST by adding parent pointers for each node, and a count of the total number of children under each node (which you can do when building the tree for no extra asymptotic cost).

To solve the problem, then, count the total number of children under the given node's left subtree (constant time, since you just look that up in the augmented tree data). Then, walk the parent pointers towards the root. At each parent, if you came from the right subtree, add the left subtree child count to the total count.

Because your tree is balanced, you will only do O(log n) work as you walk to the root.

Answer (score 0):

If you can store weight of subtrees for each node , you can do it in (log n) (one search for your target).
Do search for your target and count weights,

### Code

```
class node{
public:
    int value;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    int leftWeight;
    int rightWeight;
    node(int value, node* left, node* right, int leftWeight, int rightWeight){
    this->value = value;
    this->left = left;
    this->right = right;
    this->leftWeight = leftWeight;
    this->rightWeight = rightWeight;
   }
}; 

void search_tree(node* root, int key){

bool found = false;
node* tmp = root;
int greaterCount, smallerCount;
greaterCount = smallerCount = 0;

while (!found && tmp != nullptr){

    if (key < tmp->value){
        // +1 for tmp it self
        greaterCount += tmp->rightWeight + 1;
        tmp = tmp->left;
    }
    else if (key > tmp->value){
        // +1 for tmp it self
        smallerCount += tmp->leftWeight + 1;
        tmp = tmp->right;
    }
    else {
        // found
        found = true;           
        smallerCount += tmp->leftWeight;
        greaterCount += tmp->rightWeight;
    }
}

// If element isn't found , you can delete this
if (!found){
    cout << "targer not found" << endl;
    return;
}

cout << "Elements greater than " << key << ": " << greaterCount << endl
     << "Elements smaller than " << key << ": " << smallerCount << endl;

}

int main() {

/*
    Tree

    .....................(10)........................
    .................../.....\.......................
    .................(5).....(20)....................
    .............../...\..../....\...................
    .............(4)..(8)..(11)...(40)...............
    ............/.............\......................
    ...........(1)............(12)....................


*/


//Left subtree
node* n1 = new node(1, nullptr, nullptr, 0, 0);
node* n4 = new node(4, n1, nullptr, 1, 0);
node* n8 = new node(8, nullptr, nullptr, 0, 0);
node* n5 = new node(5, n4, n8, 2, 1);

//Right subtree
node* n12 = new node(12, nullptr, nullptr, 0, 0);
node* n11 = new node(11, nullptr, n12, 0, 1);
node* n40 = new node(40, nullptr, nullptr, 0, 0);
node* n20 = new node(20, n11, n40, 2, 1);

// Root
node* n10 = new node(10, n5, n20, 4, 4);

search_tree(n10, 12);

return 0;
}
```

### Details

I assumed that tree already created ( you can update weights while inserting nodes ),
every time you enter node and it's not your target check if it's grater than or smaller than your target .
if it's greater, the right subtree of this node will also be grater than your target then update greaterCount.
the same thing with left subtree if node is smaller than your target.